# is it possible to insert data from other web site?

Tags: java, php, database

My English's suck, please understand it.

I am a beginner in programming field.
What i am trying to make these day is making an Accommodation Booking website.

Here's my detailed idea, 
I will make Booking System in my own server as well as database.
and then provide other accommodation website with some XMLs or like, so that they can see their own reservation information stored in my database on their website. I think this is possible.

but my goal is not only getting information from my own database, but also inserting a booking data into my database from their website without giving them my database access id/passwd.

I have completely no idea for this.,

can Anybody tell me which i need to know or learn for this, thank you good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, the other site would have a public API you could use to obtain its data.

Otherwise, you could use a screen scraping technique with cURL.  Here's an example: http://devtrench.com/posts/screen-scrape-with-php-curl

Comment: thank you for answering, i think i need to look into more on Public API.

Comment: It just depends what site you want to get the data from. Some travel sites allow you to access their data via an API. Expedia: http://developer.ean.com/ Tripit: http://www.tripit.com/developer

Comment: Yeah, using an api is more reliable. (Not to mention most sites prohibit screen scraping anyway.)